# rails - how to unistall ckeditor from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

First I installed CKEditor, but then I found a simple text editor and want to remove CKEditor. But nowhere is there any word on how to do it.

Of course, I can just remove the gem from Gemfile and run `bundle`, but how I can then removed CKEditor files?

Answer (score 2):

You have inserted something into your application.js and application.css file - remove the require ckeditor stuff.

then remove it from your **Gemfile**.
then run:

```
bundle exec gem uninstall GEM_NAME
```

Also if you have your assets precompiled then run:

```
rake assets:clean assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

To remove it from the public js and css files.

If you still encounter ckeditor files in your public assets folder then run:

**rake assets:clobber** and then compile it again.